# Java SimpleDateFormat parsing oddity

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am baffled why this doesn't work. No matter what I change the day to, it prints out the same thing. What is going on here?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
String s = "11/22/2000";
Date d = sdf.parse(s);
System.out.println(d.toString());
```

Output: `Sun Dec 26 00:00:00 CST 1999`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `YYYY` which is the week-year instead of the "normal" year. That's usually only used with day-of-week and week-of-year specifiers.

The *exact* behaviour here would be hard to explain - feasible, but not terribly helpful. Basically the solution is "don't do that". You want a format string of `MM/dd/yyyy` instead - note the case of the `yyyy`.

(As a side note, if you can possibly use `java.time.*` from Java 8 or Joda Time, you'll have a lot better time in Java with date/time issues. It wouldn't affect this particular issue, but it's generally a good idea...)

Comment: I would be interested in understanding how the `YYYY` format works, because it produces a different result in the UK `Locale` (`Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 EET 2000`). It would be great if Java had a type-safe formatter to prevent easy-to-make errors such as this one (also the case of `dd` and `MM` matter).

Comment: Wow what a silly thing to ruin everything! The requirements I was working from had it in the uppercase format, so I just blindly used it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

instead of

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
```